# how to get/print alert text into my eclipse console window in selenium using javascript

Tags: javascript, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

image link (( [green box is an input text field, red box is an alert message, i need to print this alert message in eclipse console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uARjb.png)

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='pick_up_pincode']")).sendKeys("577205");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='drop_pincode']")).sendKeys("560001");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-raised btn-default show-sls btn-design']")).click();

//Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert(); (as this is to handle window, but my webpage is displayed as shown in attached window)
//System.out.println(alert.getText());
//  alert.accept();
```

here is an html tag

```
<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);" id="pick_up_pincode_error"><b>Sorry ! This pincode is not serviceable.</b> </span>
<span style="color:#ff0000;display: none;" id="pick_up_pincode_empty">Please enter the pincode</span>
<input class="form-control index-color" id="pick_up_pincode" maxlength="6" pattern="([0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9])" placeholder="Enter pick up pincode" value="" type="text">
```

Comment: I think the DOM must contain a html tag for that alert text. Have you tried to check it?

Comment: you are right, an html tag has been used for the alert text.. can i print this on console?

Answer (score 1):

To print the alert text on console, I think you can do like:

```
var text = driver.findElement(By.id("pick_up_pincode_error")).getText();
console.log(text);
```